# Using CRTP with same member function name

Tags: c++, inheritance, crtp

When I see the CRTP pattern used, it appears that the function name called in the base type always points to an implementation function of a different name in the derived type (ex: `foo()` in base makes the call `static_cast<DerivedType*>(this)->foo_implementation();`.

Is there a way to implement the CRTP pattern using the same function name? I have a longer inheritance chain in which the function might not have a concrete implementation in the first level of the chain, so having to use different function names is not very clean/readable.

I want to have something like the following:

```
template <typename SecondType>
struct FirstType {

    void foo() {
        static_cast<SecondType*>(this)->foo();
    }

};

template <typename ThirdType>
struct SecondType : FirstType<SecondType> {

    void foo() {
        static_cast<ThirdType*>(this)->foo();
    }

};

struct ThirdType : SecondType<ThirdType> {

    void foo() {
        // Concrete implementation here
    }

};
```

Of course the compiler does not complain about this, but I would imagine that it results in an implicit vtable lookup (despite the `virtual` keyword not appearing), defeating the purpose of using the CRTP.

Comment: As your functions aren't virtual, there are no vtables.

Comment: Sorry, modified code snippet to reflect CRTP.

Comment: SecondType seems useless.  If there are missing details, it should anyhow inherit from `FirstType<ThirdType>`. and have no `foo` method.  Finally I have no idea what the "first level" in your chain is.  You have thrown out too many details to determine what you actually want possibly, or your design is bad.  I cannot tell.

Answer (score 5):

You can very well use the same name for both functions, it will work fine.

The advantage of using a different name is that failing to implement the function in the derived class will result in a compiler error, instead of an infinite recursion and probable stack overflow at runtime.

Comment: I understand. Because of that, is it generally frowned upon to use the same function name when writing an API, or is this common practice as well?

Answer (score 1):

Why not assert that the member functions are different? Removing the foo() from ThirdType will give you a compile error with a nice message.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename SecondType>
struct FirstType {

    void foo() {
        static_assert(
            !std::is_same<
                decltype(&FirstType::foo),
                decltype(&SecondType::foo)
             >::value,
            "SecondType must implement method 'void foo()'");
        static_cast<SecondType*>(this)->foo();
    }

};

template <typename ThirdType>
struct SecondType : FirstType<SecondType<ThirdType>> {

    void foo() {
        static_assert(
            !std::is_same<
                decltype(&SecondType::foo),
                decltype(&ThirdType::foo)
             >::value,
            "ThirdType must implement method 'void foo()'");
        static_cast<ThirdType*>(this)->foo();
    }

};

struct ThirdType : SecondType<ThirdType> {

    void foo() {
        // Concrete implementation here
    }

};

template class SecondType<ThirdType>;
template class FirstType<SecondType<ThirdType>>;
```